# Trying to create objects in a for loop in pygame and get AttributeError: 'FoodItems' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

Tags: python, pygame

Basically I'm trying to write some code which displays food items on the screen and I'm using a class structure to create these objects.I'm then putting them in a sprite group and then displaying this sprite group on the screen However I get this error when running the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "N:/Y12/Computer
>   science/Consumo/Consumo V8.5.py", line 172, in 
>       menuScreen()   File "N:/Y12/Computer science/Consumo/Consumo V8.5.py", line 113, in menuScreen
>       button("Play Game",850,340,120,50,blue,gameLoop)#Puts theree button on the screen   File "N:/Y12/Computer science/Consumo/Consumo
>   V8.5.py", line 99, in button
>       action()   File "N:/Y12/Computer science/Consumo/Consumo V8.5.py", line 160, in gameLoop
>       allSprites.add(food)   File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 378, in add
>       sprite.add_internal(self) AttributeError: 'FoodItems' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

Here is my code I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this error as I don't even know what the error means.:

```
    #Imports the libaries I will use 
    import pygame,time,random
    pygame.init()

    #Sets up the variables for the screen size 
    displayWidth = 1000
    displayHeight = 600
    weight = 0
    lives = 0 
    clock= pygame.time.Clock()

    #sets up the variables for the colours 
    black = (0 ,0 ,0)
    red = (200 ,0 ,0)
    grey = (128 ,128 ,128)
    blue = (0, 0, 200)
    green= (0,255,0)

    #Sets up the images and re-sizes them and also adds the music file
    character =pygame.image.load("character.png")
    character = pygame.transform.scale(character,(60,60))
    sumo = pygame.image.load("sumo .jpg")
    sumo = pygame.transform.scale(sumo,(60,60))

    #both background images are set to displayHeight,displayWidth so they fit the screen
    dojoBackDrop = pygame.image.load("dojo.png")
    dojoBackDrop = pygame.transform.scale(dojoBackDrop,(displayWidth,displayHeight))
    menuBackDrop =  pygame.image.load("menu screen .png")
    menuBackDrop = pygame.transform.scale(menuBackDrop,(displayWidth,displayHeight))

    foodSizeX = 45#I have set up a variable to re-size all the images to as 
    foodSizeY = 45
    0#I want them to be the same size 
    #loads all the food images for my food 
    apple = pygame.image.load("Apple .png")
    apple = pygame.transform.scale(apple,(foodSizeX,foodSizeY))
    fish  = pygame.image.load("Fish.png")
    fish = pygame.transform.scale(fish,(foodSizeX,foodSizeY))
    rice = pygame.image.load("Rice_fresh.png")
    rice = pygame.transform.scale(rice,(foodSizeX,foodSizeY))


    rottenApple = pygame.image.load("rottenapple.png")
    rottenApple = pygame.transform.scale(rottenApple,(foodSizeX,foodSizeY))
    rottenFish = pygame.image.load("rottenfish.png")
    rottenFish = pygame.transform.scale(rottenFish,(foodSizeX,foodSizeY))

    rottenRice = pygame.image.load("rottenrice.png")
    rottenRice = pygame.transform.scale(rottenRice,(foodSizeX,foodSizeY))

    #loads the music which will be playing during the game
    #file has been converted from mp3 to ogg as python can't read mp3 
    #backGroundMusic = pygame.mixer.Sound("Bully Scholarship Edition Soundtrack - Arcade Game - ConSumo (Game) (1).ogg")
    #sets up the pygame window with height and width variables created above 
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth,displayHeight))
    images =[apple,rice,fish]


    class FoodItems:
        def __init__(self,weightIncrease,xChange,yChange): 
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.weightIncrease = weightIncrease


            #sets attributes for the class by using the self
                        # this is so they can be set to What I chose 

            self.image  = random.choice(images)
            self.rect= self.image.get_rect()
            self.rectX  = random.randrange(displayWidth - self.rect.width) #creates a hit box for my object 
            self.rectY  = random.randrange(displayHeight-self.rect.height)
            self.xChange = xChange # sets a random speed for x and y 
            self.yChange = yChange
        def update():#conitnusly updates the sprite on the screen 

            self.rectX +=  self.xChange
            self.rectY += sel.yChange #keeps moving the objects
            if self.rectx > displayHeight +10:
                self.rect.x = random.randrange(displayWidth-self.rect.width)
                self.rect.y = random.randrange(displayHeight-self.rect.height)
                                        #this will make the object be able to move

    allSprites=pygame.sprite.Group()#creates a group of sprites on the screen 





    def textObjects(text,font):#passes parameters by value
        textSurface = font.render(text,True,black)#renders the font and sets the color as black
        return textSurface,textSurface.get_rect()#gets the dimensions of the text  

    def button(msg,x,y,w,h,c,action=None):#passes the parameters by value  
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()#this gets the postion of the mouse
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()#checks to see where the mouse has been clicked
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, c,(x,y,w,h))#draws a rectangle with on the game display with the parameters given
        if x+w > mouse[0] >x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:#checks to see if the mouse has been clicked anywhere in the button 
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:#if the mouse has been clicked performed an action 
                action()
        smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
        textSurf , textRect = textObjects(msg ,smallText)
        #sets the message of the button
        textRect.center = ((x+(w/2),(y+(h/2))))#centers the text on screen 
        gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)#puts the button on screen with the text 

    def menuScreen():
        screenOn = True 
        while screenOn ==True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#allows user to quit the game
                    quit()
                gameDisplay.blit(menuBackDrop,(0,0))#sets the image to the size of the screen
                button("Play Game",850,340,120,50,blue,gameLoop)#Puts theree button on the screen 
                button("Leaderboard",850,440,120,50,blue)
                button("Quit game",850,540,120,50,blue)
                pygame.display.update()#updates the screen so things can appear on it

    def gameLoop():
        #backGroundMusic.play()
        playerX =500  #used to set the characters position as the center of the screen 
        playerY = 300
        playerXChange = 0#value at which x and ywill change when a Key is pressed                          
        playerYChange = 0
        playing = True #boolean so that the while loop knows when to run till 
        while playing ==True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#allows user to quit the game
                    quit()
            #if any key is pressed perfomr an action 
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:#if   A is pressed move ten to the left 
                        playerXChange = -5
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_d:#if D is pressed move ten to the right 
                        playerXChange = 5
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_w:#if  W is pressed move ten up 
                        playerYChange = -5 
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:#if S is pressed move ten down
                        playerYChange = 5

                if event.type ==pygame.KEYUP:
                    playerXChange =0
                    playerYChange =0

            if playerX < 0: #if players x value is less than set it to zero
                playerX = 0
            if playerX >940:#if players x value is greater than 940 than set it to 940
                playerX = 940
            if playerY < 0:#if players y value is less than set it to zero
                playerY = 0
            if playerY >540:#if players y value is greater than 540 set it to 540 
                playerY = 540



            playerX = playerX+playerXChange
            playerY = playerY+playerYChange#makes the character x and y change by the value set in the code above
            gameDisplay.blit(dojoBackDrop,(0,0))
            for i in range(8):#loops to get 8 food on the screen at once
                food =FoodItems(5,5,5)#instatiates an object 
                allSprites.add(food)#adds object to sprite group 



            #instantiate a new object
            allSprites.update()#updates all sprites 
            allSprites.draw(gameDisplay)#draws all the sprites on the screen                                     
            gameDisplay.blit(character,(playerX,playerY))
            pygame.display.update()



    menuScreen()
```

I want the images to display on screen and keep moving but they I just can't get past this error.

Comment: I know it might be hard, but there is too many code in your example. Try removing the parts that are not related to this specific error then it is more likely that you'll find a good answer here (also it might already help you find what's happening). It seems to me the error is in this line `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)`, it is possible that you are expected to implement the method `add_internal` in your `FoodItem`, but honestly you should just check what the docs says about this.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to subclass pygame's sprite class with your `FoodItems` class. If that is the case, you should try using `class FoodItems(pygame.sprite.Sprite)` instead of `class FoodItems` to indicate this inheritance. Then your class would know to use the superclass's definition for `add_internal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to and an object to a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), then the class of the object has to be derived from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
class FoodItems(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,weightIncrease,xChange,yChange): 
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # [...]
```

Further, the "self" attribute is missing in the method `.update()`:

```py
class FoodItems(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def update(self): #conitnusly updates the sprite on the screen 

        self.rectX += self.xChange
        self.rectY += self.yChange #keeps moving the objects
        if self.rect.x > displayHeight +10:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(displayWidth-self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(displayHeight-self.rect.height)
                                    #this will make the object be able to move
```